# How to dynamically create a cartesian chart using livecharts

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, cartesian, livecharts

Can anyone tell me how to create cartesian chart dynamically in C# code?
I created an instance of cartesian chart with `CartesianChart ch = new CartesianChart();` but do I need to add series, margins, etc? Basically I need to create wpf cartesian chart in code which will then be showed in wpf application.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below a simple example to programmatically create a CartesianChart instance and apply it to a named WPF element. As a minimum your CartesianChart needs some data to display, which is defined within a SeriesCollection and set to the Series property.

Code behind:

```
    CartesianChart ch = new CartesianChart();
    ch.Series = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "Series 1",
            Values = new ChartValues<double> { 1, 1, 2, 3 ,5 }
        }
    };
    TestGrid.Children.Add(ch);
```

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="TestGrid"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you tell me how to add Legend on chart but programmatically? 
I am new to this and there is no too much documentation about creating dynamically (in code) live charts :/

Comment: There is a LegendLocation property on the CartesianChart class - for example add "ch.LegendLocation = LegendLocation.Right" to make the legend appear on the right hand side of the chart. Hope this helps! If you have any further queries please add as a new question.

Comment: can you tellme the flow if I get a value from a textbox in XAML and then the control comes to button_click() function in xaml.cs and write the chart generation code there but then how do I inject the chart below the textfeld in .xaml file

Comment: Zavy - do you want the chart to appear only once an entry has been made in the textbox?